# I Need to get the XML Parent Tag Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

This code gets a value of a xml tag using the attribute, I need to reverse this operation and get a attribute value using a tag name of an xml.

```
XElement main = XElement.Load(fi.FullName);

//Linq query for searching Ports address by ID Attributes
IEnumerable<XElement> searched =
from ports in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/Ports")
where (string)ports.Attribute("id") == fi.Name.Substring(0,36)
select ports;
```

This is not working but it should be something around this procedure I am trying to get the attribute where the tag name is matching.

```
//Something more like this
IEnumerable<XElement> searchedat =
                from netatt in main.FirstAttribute = "id"
                where netatt.Name == "Network"
                select netatt;
```

Comment: please post the XML structure you are working with and full code. What is main?

Comment: the main Is the XELEMENT XML object or you can say its the xml file I am trying to parse the attribute value

Comment: What collection do you expect to come from this expression **main.FirstAttribute = "id"**? It is what you are iterating over in your experimental code. Don't you mean **main.Elements().Where(el=>el.FirstAttribute.Name=="id")**?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("XML String");
var attributeValue = xDoc.Root.Element("Name of the element").Attribute("Name of attribute").Value
```

you might have to parse the xml tree a little further depending upon your XML structure

Comment: I just want the parent ID Attribute value, I already have the document in the code I just need the linq query code, I also want to know if you have it using the XElement object code for Linq

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> searched =
from ports in main.XPathSelectElements("Network/Ports")
where ports.LocalName == "TagNameToCompareHere"
select ports.Attribute("id").Value;
```